# inserting the table colomn data in multiple tables colomn.(SQL SERVER)

Tags: sql-server, trigger, sql-server-agent

I want to insert one table colomn data into multiple tables colomns using triggers. 
For Example: I have one table name 'T1' having multiple colomns like 'C1','C2','C3' and now I want to insert these colomns data in table 'T2','T3','T4' having same colomn names 'C1','C2','C3' by using trigger.

Can anybody please help me out?

Comment: What, exactly have you tried? Did you Google/research trigger syntax? Voting to close unless the OP shows some effort. Take the tour and read the "help us to help you" blog (bottom left of page),

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_t1
   ON  T1
   FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    insert into T2(C1,C2,C3 )
    select  C1,C2,C3 
    from    inserted    


    insert into T3(C1,C2,C3 )
    select  C1,C2,C3 
    from    inserted    


    insert into T4(C1,C2,C3 )
    select  C1,C2,C3 
    from    inserted    

END
GO
```

DML trigger statements use two special tables: the deleted table and the inserted tables. SQL Server automatically creates and manages these tables.

```
                                                                                      :MSDN
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx